# Add Action to Form in HTML using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am attempting to add the action attribute to my form element, on the load of a jquery function. However, I seem to be missing something. I have tried searching for this issue, and I have not found any luck in regards to my issue. Here is the HTML in question:

```
 <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="#photouploader">
            Upload Client Photo Here
            <input type="file" name="thumbnail">
            <input type="submit" value="Upload Image">
          </form>
```

This is the Jquery function I wrote:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 var id = document.location.href.split('client/')[1]; 
 $('#photouploader').attr('action', '/form-upload/'+id);
 });
```

I am just looking to understand where I am going wrong here.

Comment: remove the # from the id attribute in the HTML

Answer (score 2):

You have a `#` in your HTML form ID - Remove it and your jQuery should work. Should look like this:

`<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="photouploader">`

The `#` in jquery is not part of the ID, it just indicates that the following text is referencing an element ID, similar to how `.` indicates class.

**EDIT:** Credit to [eatpeanutbutter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2175593/eatpeanutbutter), he had the correct answer in the comments originally. I was typing mine up as it was posted.

Comment: @EatPeanutButter I was typing my answer up as you commented so I did not see yours before adding mine, AND I cited you in my answer once I realized. That being said, if you had the answer, why not post it AS an answer? Additionally, you actually submitted an answer AFTER my answer, so who's hijacking rep again?

Comment: You do not get rep from comments. In this case, the question was not even worth answering. Question has been close-marked as typo. Down-voter should remove downvote. Simultaneous answering can happen

Comment: I have removed the # in front of id. However, my method still seems not to work.

Comment: @tetraphenom I've tried your code above in this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uxoxL7js/   and after doing an inspect element, it is definitely adding the action. Are you sure that your URL has the string 'client/' in it? If you check in console, are you getting any errors?

Comment: Regarding the URL, yes -- I am successfully running other code using same variable with same definition. Also, I am not getting any errors. However, once I check the html after compiling, the action does not appear in the form.

Answer (score 2):

Your selector `$('#photouploader').attr('action', '/form-upload/'+id);` is looking for an id called `photouploader`. You do not have an HTML element with an ID of `photouploader`.  Instead, you have an element with an ID of `#photouploader`.

Simply remove the `#` from your ID attribute in the HTML and you should be good to go -

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="photouploader">
```

Comment: @mplungjan Quite honestly, because after posting my answer, the user commented on mine saying I was "stealing his rep" - He then posted his own answer 2 minutes AFTER that comment, leading me to believe it was knowingly submitted as a duplicate, not simultaneously. I've removed my downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Remove # from id (id="photouploader">) and try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var id = document.location.href.split('client/')[1]; 
 $('#photouploader').attr('action', '/form-upload/'+id);
});
```

Comment: I have tried this. After looking in inspect element, I still could not find action embedded into the form element

Comment: I change a response